# Binding the React component to a Handontable instance

Tags: javascript, reactjs, handsontable

After `react-handsontable` was upgraded to version 1.0.0, I'm not quite sure how to bind the React component to a Handsontable instance, since `Handsontable` is now a peer dependency, and no longer part of the React wrapper, and so it can't be accessed by a reference anymore.

The `react-handsontable` docs show how to render the `Handsontable` component:

```
render() {
  return (
    <div id="hot-app">
      <HotTable data={this.data} colHeaders={true} rowHeaders={true} width="600" height="300" stretchH="all" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the Handsontable Core API reference shows how to call its methods:

```
var ht = new Handsontable(document.getElementById('example1'), options);
```

So I tried adding an ID to the React component and creating a new instance of `Handsontable` that references that element, but it just ends up rendering another table:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const hot = new Handsontable(document.getElementById('hot'));
  // hot.countCols();
}

render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <HotTable id="hot" settings={...} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

How can I use the Core API methods with the rendered component? I've also [raised an issue](https://github.com/handsontable/react-handsontable/issues/75) in an attempt to improve the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that `HotTable` has a `hotInstance` – an instance of `Handsontable` – and you still need to add a reference to your component to access it. So following my previous example, it should look something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.hotRef = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount() {
  const hotInstance = this.hotRef.current.hotInstance;
  // hotInstance.countCols();
}

render() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <HotTable ref={this.hotRef} settings={...} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

An alternative to `React.createRef()` is [callback refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).